# Mouse get on one element and changing all the other similars elements using css

Tags: html, css

My little Html code is :

```
<div class="PDA">A</div>
<div class="PDA">B</div>
<div class="PDA">C</div>
<div class="PDA">D</div>
<div class="PDA">E</div>
<div class="PDA">F</div>
```

So my problem is that i want to change background of **all** the *PDA* div's when for example the **A** div getting mouse hover.

I also used this css code but I can't do the thing i need :

```
.PDA:hover .PDA{
background : #fff;
}
.PDA .PDA:hover{
background : #000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put one div at the top of the page (like this):

```
<div class="class">

<div class="PDA">A</div>
<div class="PDA">B</div>
<div class="PDA">C</div>
<div class="PDA">D</div>
<div class="PDA">E</div>
<div class="PDA">F</div>

</div>
```

and CSS code :

`.class:hover .PDA{
background : green;
}
.class .PDA:hover{
background : red;
}`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDC6y/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `hover` pseudoevent as seen in the linked JSFiddle.

```
$('.PDA').hover(function(){
  $('.PDA').addClass('highlight');
},function(){
  $('.PDA').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NtCeL/5/)

Edit: A better answer is in my opinion [using purely CSS with a wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/NtCeL/2/), but this is not useful in every case, as it also triggers on hovering over the space between the single elements.